# What's the right approach to manually adding a callback to an existing module method?

Tags: python, events, callback, patch

For example...

There are several methods that I'd like to treat as 'events', and fire my own functions once they've been called.

I do not manually invoke these.

As someone that's not well-versed with Python, but familiar with C#, I'd ideally like to be able patch into a module method, and either alter functionality, or just callback my own methods.

edit: example added

```
def my_own_callback_method():
    # do something here


# imagine in a large code base there's a method I'd like to target and fire my own callback ...
#
# ... something else invokes a method ('not_my_method') in a third-party module ('core').


def not_my_method():
    # the orginial function executes as it would
    # 
    # but I'd like to pre/post callback my own method from my module
    my_own_callback_method()
```

Alternatively, it'd be nice to be able to 'patch' a method and alter its functionality. Example below -

```
# again, imagine in a large code base there's a method I'd like to target ...
# ... but I'd like to alter the way this method works in my own module.
# 
# kind of like...


def my_method(something:str, something_else:int):
    # my own method patch of how the original 'not_my_method' should work

def not_my_method(something:str, something_else:int):
    return my_method(something, something_else)
```

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have *any* control over `not_my_method`'s code it will be (almost?) impossible since you want to actually change its source code.

I believe that the best you can achieve is wrapping it in your own function that calls `my_method` after it calls `not_my_method`, but that would be pretty much it.

Perhaps you are looking at it from the wrong angle. It might be easier to patch the actual event that calls `not_my_method` than patching `not_my_method` itself.

Comment: Being able to alter a method's functionality was a push to what I'm used to in C# - it's more of a 'would be nice to have' case. My current approach for allowing pre & post callbacks is to use an injector decorator and pass through the target method, and any args. Not so sure if that's the right way to handle such thing though.